# Proving a canonical height property

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, minimal-polynomials

Let $H$ be the classical Weil height for a number field (of degree $n$ say), i.e. given $\alpha$ an element of this field and $f(x) = a_0x^n + \cdots + a_n \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ its minimal polynomial, the height is defined by
$$H(\alpha)^n = |a_0|\prod_i \max(1, |\alpha_i|)$$
where the $\alpha_i$ are the different complex embeddings of $\alpha$.

I would like to prove that $H(\alpha^m) = H(\alpha)^m$. It seems to be derived from the fact that
$$g(x) = a_0^m (x-\alpha_1^m) \cdots (X-\alpha_n^m)$$
has the following properties, that I am struggling to understand:

- a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ (I can factor it by $f(x)$, but it is not so clear to see how the remaining coefficients are also integers, maybe with the root-coefficients Newton relations?)
- a power of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha^m$ (it is surely a multiple, since it kills $\alpha^m$ which is among one of the $\alpha_i^m$)

Thanks a lot for tips or help!

Answer (score 0):

If we let $\omega$ be the $m$th root of unity, we have:

$$g(x^m)=\prod_{i=1}^m f(\omega^i x) \omega^{-in}$$

Since $\omega$ is an algebraic integer, all the coefficients on the RHS are algebraic integers, so all the coefficients of $g$ are algebraic integers.

Also, all the coefficients of $g$ are symmetric polynomials of ratios of the coefficients of $f$, so they must be rational, so they must be integers.

Let $p$ be any arbitrary prime, let’s show that $p$ does not divide $g$. Since $f$ is a minimal polynomial, it has some term not divisible by $p$. Let that term be $a_p x^{n_p}$.  Then, working mod $p$, $g(x^m)$ must have leading term $a_p^m x^{m n_p} (-1)^{(n_p-n)m(m+1)}$.  This is not divisible by $p$, so $g$ must not be divisible by $p$. Thus, $g$ is not divisible by any primes, so its coefficients are in lowest terms.

Consider the Galois group of the splitting field of $f$. It must act transitively on $\alpha_i$.  If we consider the subgroup of automorphisms which stabilizes $a_1^n$, we’ll find that it’s cosets correspond to the various values of of $a_i^n$ with the size of each orbit being the same. Thus, for some $k$ and $h(x)$, we have that $g(x)=h(x)^k$ where $h$ has distinct roots. Since $h(\alpha^n)=0$, it must divide the minimal polynomial, and since the automorphism group acts transitively on its roots, it must be irreducible. Thus, it is the minimal polynomial.